# Python - open file - readline - list - convert to string

Tags: python, string, list, join, readline

The Issue/Question Details

I have a file (blah.txt) where its contents (a list) look like this:

Key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']

Inside of a simple python file (called CAT.py) I execute the following commands:

```
infile = open('blah.txt', 'r')
Key1 = infile.readline()
infile.close()
Key1 = Key1.rstrip('\n')
print(Key1)
```

> > > Key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']

```
print(''.join(Key1))
```

> > > Key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']  <---- THIS IS WHAT I DO NOT WANT

However….

If in a separate simple python file (called DOG.py) I execute the following commands on a list:

Key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']

print(Key1)

> > > ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ']

print(''.join(Key1))

> > > ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ    <---- THIS IS WHAT I WANT

The Issue/Question

I ultimately want the output that looks like “ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ”, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to read in a list for a file and then convert that list to a single string of characters. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong and also show me some code that would fix my problem?

Comment: Your `Key1` is `<class 'str'>` instead of `<class 'list'>`, that's why the `join()` wouldn't work as you expect

Comment: It doesnt sound like you have a good reason to save raw python code in a text file. @Matthias did answer this question though, but you should have a better way to save your daa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> infile = open('blah.txt', 'r')
>>> key1 = infile.readline()
>>> infile.close()
>>> key1 = "Key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']"
>>> key1 = key1[key1.index('['):key1.index(']')+1]
>>> key1
"['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']"
>>> ''.join(eval(key1))
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '
```

Comment: This suggestion worked great. I especially like the fact that I did not need to import a module to complete the task - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to transform the `string` to a `list` before you can apply `join`.

First we use `partition` to get the part after the `=`. Then `ast.literal_eval` will create a list out of the string.

```
import ast
line = "Key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']"
data = line.partition('=')[2].strip()
elements = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(''.join(elements))
```

Additional: You could use `with` in the context of opening the file. If you do it, Python will close the file for you.

```
with open('blah.txt', 'r') as infile:
    line = infile.readline()
```

As jamylak pointed out: If you control the file please don't store the data like this. As you can see it's not easy to handle. You could store and read the data as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
infile = open('blah.txt', 'r')
Key1 = infile.read()
import re
y=re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z])",Key1.split("=")[1])
print "".join(y)
```

You can simply try this.

Answer (score 0):

use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
import ast
with open('blah.txt') as f:
    for line in f:   # line = 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' '.
        print ''.join(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

use `str.split` and split by `=` and then select the list of characters by indexing `[-1]` will gives you last index which carry the list of characters and then use `ast.literal_eval` to get the character and then use `str.join` to join all the characters.

```
import ast
with open('blah.txt') as f:
    for line in f:  # if line = key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']
        print ''.join(ast.literal_eval(line.split(' = ')[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

YOur problem is that in your first example key1 is a string and not a list.  The following should give you the desired output:

```
str_input = "Key1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ']"

remove_unnecessary_data = str_input[str_input.find('[')+1: str_input.find(']')]

answer = ''.join([char for char in remove_unnecessary_data  if char not in("'", ",")])
```

Answer (score 0):

import re

string = ""

read = open('blah.txt', 'r')

key = read.readline()

a = re.compile("[A-Z]")

for char in key:

```
    if a.match(char):

            string = string + char
```

print string